# Unable using Runtime.exec() to execute shell command "echo" in Android Java code

Tags: java, android, shell, echo, runtime.exec

I can use `Runtime.exec()` to execute shell commands like "`getprop`" and "`ls system`" and they work fine.

However, when I use "`echo $BOOTCLASSPATH`", "`echo \\$BOOTCLASSPATH`" or "`echo HelloWorld`", it won't show it in stdout.

The logcat shows:

```
I/AndroidRuntime( 4453): VM exiting with result code -1.
```

Here's my code:

```
try {
    java.lang.Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo -e \\$BOOTCLASSPATH");
    String line = null;

    InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader esr = new InputStreamReader (stderr);
    BufferedReader ebr = new BufferedReader (esr);
    while ( (line = ebr.readLine()) != null )
        Log.e("FXN-BOOTCLASSPATH", line);

    InputStream stdout = proc.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader osr = new InputStreamReader (stdout);
    BufferedReader obr = new BufferedReader (osr);
    while ( (line = obr.readLine()) != null )
        Log.i("FXN-BOOTCLASSPATH", line);

    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    Log.d("FXN-BOOTCLASSPATH", "getprop exitValue: " + exitVal);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hope [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1982879?start=0) will help you.

Comment: It seems that you don't have a /bin/echo on that system; echo is also available as a shell command. Try to exec `sh -c "echo -e \\$BOOTCLASSPATH"`

Comment: @user3505725 That link refers to troubles on Windows. Ick.

Comment: I tried this:
    `String[] cmdline = { "sh", "-c", "echo $BOOTCLASSPATH" };`
    `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline);`
and it works.
Thank you guys.

Comment: Thanks Buddy @QYLin , you saved my life. can you elaborate why does this happen?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@Adi Tiwari, I've found the cause.
`Runtime.getRuntime.exec()` doesn't execute a shell command directly, it executes an executable with arguments.
"`echo`" is a builtin shell command. It is actually a part of the argument of the executable `sh` with the option `-c`.
Commands like `ls` are actual executables.
You can use `type echo` and `type ls` command in `adb shell` to see the difference.
So final code is:

```
String[] cmdline = { "sh", "-c", "echo $BOOTCLASSPATH" }; 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline);
```

Comment: NOTE: I wanted to better understand this explanation - in particular the theoretical part behind - and I found [this article](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3342440/how-to-identify-shell-builtins-aliases-and-executable-files-on-linux-systems.html) absolutely useful for this purpose

Comment: Sorry this is an old topic but what about multi commands in this case not only one single echo command?

Comment: Kind of surprised that no one has mentioned that shell built-ins (including `echo`) often have executable correlates.  On most normal linux systems, `which echo` will return `/bin/echo` but `type echo` will return `echo is a shell builtin`.   This is not the case on Android, however.