# Java: using bash commands "No such file or directory" when using >> and file exists in working directory

Tags: java, bash, file

I am trying to append to a file using a bash command in java, this has been appropriately set up using the standard method

```
private static void commitToFile(String xy, String fileName) {
    bashHook(xy + System.lineSeparator() + " >> " + fileName);
    System.out.println(bashHook("pwd"));
}
```

causes this :

[image]

the file passed as `fileName` exists, verbatim, in the src directory, i am unsure why the command is not working.

Comment: Do you really need Bash for this? Why not just use Java standard `Files` APIs instead?

Comment: I've done it using the standard methods, Files.write etc and it works, but now i'd like to do it this way.

Comment: update: i think i have to use echo " " >> file here, possibly.

Comment: ugh, absolutely, problem solved, thanks

Comment: Looks like you also picked the missing `echo`... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
bashHook(“echo ” + xy + " >> " + fileName);
```

I think you missed the actual output command ;)

Comment: also the lineSeparator isnt needed.. the issue is now, actually, it doesn't throw an error anymore, but the file is blank, despite the command being properly formatted

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(echo.. . >>.. ) doesnt seem to want to work, other commands execute... pussibly solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199307/unable-using-runtime-exec-to-execute-shell-command-echo-in-android-java-code

Comment: @JohnBap `echo` is a built-in Bash command. As such, you need to call `bash` as your first command.