# Using Linux echo command to write in a android File Programmatically

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, echo, android-external-storage

The requirement is to write a file using echo command in any location such as "/sys/bus/i2c/devices/4-0024/command" here **command** is the file name where the value to be written.

I tried below code but it's not working

```
    private void writeCommand(String data) {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("echo "+data+" > "/sys/bus/i2c/devices/4-0024/command");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here command can be any string.
Later I got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199307/unable-using-runtime-exec-to-execute-shell-command-echo-in-android-java-code) so I tried same but no luck.

below is the code for same :

```
    private void writeCommand(String data) {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] cmnd = {"sh", "-c", "echo " + data+ ">" /sys/bus/i2c/devices/4-0024/command"};
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmnd);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> Note 1: I need to use shell command only to write the file, **Not to
> use FileWriter**
>
> Note 2: My app is a system application so it has all privileged
> permissions including "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
>
> Note 3:I given linux write permission using chmod 777
>
> Note 4:android linux sepolicy is turned off.
>
> Note 5: If i use same command in command prompt,it is writing data to
> the file

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: @Onik value "data" is not writing in /command file

Comment: @pskink Do you mean we can't use **echo** to write in a file in android?

Comment: Any luck?
@Rishikeshpathak