# How to run “echo” command through Java?

Tags: java, android

I want to change a value inside of a file named scaling_max_freq located in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/ on an Android device.

On an another post I've read that I'm able to do this through an echo command like:

```java
echo 255 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

**Where "255" is the value I want to put in the file.**
How can I succeed it through java?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199307/unable-using-runtime-exec-to-execute-shell-command-echo-in-android-java-code

Comment: Yes  @Julius Hörger

Comment: I also suggest same question!

Answer (score 0):

You can do system call, [Runtime.exec()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec.htm). Or if you want to do it in pure Java you can reproduce the behavior of the command line. "echo" is just writing on the standard output, and the '>' operator is redirecting the standard output to a file (but do not append).

So in Java..

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
writer.write("255");
```